# GTM - Fire tag on form submit (only if required fields are filled)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm looking for an easy way to accurately track form submissions. This is the code I'm currently using:

```
$(function () {
      $('#form').submit(function() {
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'GAEvent', 
            'eventCat': 'Form Submit - Create', 
            'eventAction': 'Form Submit Document', 
            'eventLabel': checked,
            'eventValue': count,
            'gaNonInt': false
        });
      });
    });
```

The issue is that the tag is firing even when the form is not submitting. For example, if someone fails to fill out a required field and clicks the submit button, GTM sees that submit click as a submission. Is there an easy way to only fire the tag if all required fields are filled?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your form HTML and any JavaScript validation.

Comment: @JoshCronin I can, however, the form is massive. I'm not sure where the JS validation is stored. These forms are integrated into Drupal 7 core. I have noticed that all required fields use "required" in the naming of their classes? Could that be used somehow?

Comment: Just looking at the required attribute would probably not solve the problem completely - there might be other validation rules in place that prevent a form from being submitted even if the field contains some text.

Comment: What happens after the form is submitted? Does the page change?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try to use GTMs "native" submit trigger instead of the jQuery code and make sure that the "check validation" checkbox is ticked.

The javascript validation in your form suppresses the default behavior of the submit button and calls the submit event only when the validation has passed. With the "check validation" option set the GTM form submit trigger should be able to notice that the default behavior is prevented and fire the tags only when the validator functions calls the submit event (I say "should" because, anecdotally,  I think the form submit trigger is not always 100% reliable, but it might be worth a try).

[image]